# How to show content details when user selects from list?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am coding in react-native and using firebase realtime database as beginner level and I am new here on StackOverflow.

I am trying to figure out how I can show details of content, when the user selects from a list in another page, of that specifically selected content.

Any tips and guide would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to provide some code, that helps answering better.
If each of your list element has any unique id then you can fetch the whole list with the id from the server side. You only need to add the id somehow in the clickable list. After clicking the specific id will provide to the function.